# What is Application Context and Request Context in Flask and WerkZeug?

Tags: python, web-services, werkzeug

I am developing a web application using flask, Werkzeug and jinja2. I am very much confused with these terms and wanted to know the meaning of the terms and how they are interrelated to the CGI environment variables. What is global variable g and how it is related to the application context and request context.

Also since I don't have much knowledge of developing web apps( I am doing it for first time) any another language also so there is another request if someone could give a reference or make me understand that how the requests are handled, i mean what happens when a request arrives to the web application.

Also if i am not using any openID providers for logging in the user into my website, how can I make the password secure. Should I use any framework for that?

Comment: I suspect if you're that much of a beginner, Django will probably be a better bet for you. Especially as it comes with an authentication app that deals with storing passwords etc.

Answer (score 2):

For request context better look next question: [What is the purpose of Flask's context stacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20036520/880326). Better spend a little time to understand it because it basic framework principal.

Many approaches for user data storing will be secure, the easiest store user in database and password as `modern_crypto_hash(password + salt)` with limitation for short passwords acceptance and use something for logging as `Flask-Login` or `Flask-Principal`. To avoid SQL injections you can use any ORM, for example `SqlAlchemy`. To avoid XSS send data changing by POST and add `csrf` token, `WTForms` good there. To avoid html tags injection already use build in template system by default and do not insert user content to page unsafely. Also can be useful `https`.