# Using the global variable in flask (flask.g)

Tags: python, flask

I want to start a data load process on the server which will take 10-15 minutes.
While that process is running I want to make continuous ajax calls to the server to tell the user where the data load process is.

I have everything working; the dataload, the ajax, etc...But I can pass the status back and forth. I'm using the global g variable like this:

This function is initially called by the client. At the same time the client initiates the 5 sec polling (I have replaced some of the code with a simple time loop to make thinkes simple) :

```
@app.route('/updatedb')
def updatedb():
    while True:
        g.songcounter = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
        print(g.songcounter)
        time.sleep(1)
    models.add_collection("/media/store/Music")
    return
```

This is what the client calls every 5 sec:

```
@app.route('/dbstatus')
def dbstatus():
    if g.songcounter:
        print("status:%s" % g.songcounter)
    else:
        print("status: no")
    k = g.songcounter #time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    return render_template("dbstatus.html", timestamp=k)
```

...and this is what I get. The g.songcounter is not valid outside the update thread...
This may be fair enough...but what do I do?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2014 07:41:31] "GET /dbstatus HTTP/1.1" 500 -
07:41:31
07:41:32
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2014 07:41:33] "GET /dbstatus HTTP/1.1" 500 -
07:41:33
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2014 07:41:34] "GET /dbstatus HTTP/1.1" 500 -
07:41:34
07:41:35
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2014 07:41:36] "GET /dbstatus HTTP/1.1" 500 -
07:41:36
07:41:37
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2014 07:41:38] "GET /dbstatus HTTP/1.1" 500 -
07:41:38
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2014 07:41:39] "GET /dbstatus HTTP/1.1" 500 -
07:41:39
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with context objects as `g`. Context object live only for one thread and changed after going in or out (start request or end request for example). For details you can read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/ or another interesting question [What is the purpose of Flask's context stacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20036520/880326).

So for you case better use another shared storage user/session id as key:

- global `dict`
- server side session
- cache / redis / memcacehd
- database
- etc

Comment: global dict, redis and database is shared across users, while server/client side sessions are just for one user.

Comment: I'd be interested in what the "etc" is :-)