# What are the application and request contexts?

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask but have experience with PHP. I know there are session variables and global variables just as in PHP, but what do the contexts actually mean? I read the documentation but could not understand whet it was saying.

What are the application and request contexts, and what the is `app.app_context()`?

Comment: Is it something that you need to worry about right this instant?  That is to say, are you developing something which knowledge of this is pivotal?'

Comment: (This might seem harsh, but I'd encourage you to only learn it when you actually need to use it.  It'd just wind up confusing you more.)

Comment: No sir but im just readin the various aspects of flask frame work.?Are these not so important?

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036520/what-is-the-purpose-of-flasks-context-stacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.app_context` loads the application and any extentions you have loaded.
A request context is loaded when you are dealing with a request.

A good example.

If you have a background cron that does some database work, you'll need to make use of `app_context` to get access to the models.

You'll be a in `request context` pretty much whenever you're handling a view.