# 'application not registered on db instance' after user table truncation

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-script

I deleted all the info in my users table during testing.  Now when I try to run a `manage.py` command to recreate the admin user, I get `RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context`.  I've been reading about Flask contexts, especially [What is the purpose of Flask's context stacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036520/what-is-the-purpose-of-flasks-context-stacks), but it's not clear to me how to fix this.  How do I fix this error?

```
$ python manage.py db create_admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 58, in <module>
    manager.add_command("create_admin", create_admin())
  File "manage.py", line 47, in create_admin
    confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now()
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 150, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 878, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 704, in create_session
    return SignallingSession(self, **options)
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 149, in __init__
    self.app = db.get_app()
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 845, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError('application not registered on db '
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

`manage.py`:

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from myflaskapp.app import create_app
from myflaskapp.models.user import User
from myflaskapp.database import db

manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def create_admin():
    db.session.add(User(
        username="admin1",
        email="ad@min.com",
        password="admin",
        admin=True,
        confirmed=True,
        confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now()
    ))
    db.session.commit()

manager.add_command("create_admin", create_admin())
manager.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `@manager.command`, so you shouldn't also use `manager.add_command`.  Completely remove the line `manager.add_command('create_admin', create_admin())`.

If you want to use `add_command`, then remove `@manager.command` and use `manager.add_command('create_admin', Command(create_admin))`.

You get the error because the app context is only active when the manager is running, but you're calling the function prematurely.