# Wrong dashboard while adding flask-admin to project

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

[image]

I'm trying to extend the flask-base project https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/tree/master/app. This uses the the application factory pattern in app/init.py and blueprints.

In the app/init.py I have:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_assets import Environment
from flask_wtf import CsrfProtect
from flask_compress import Compress
from flask_rq import RQ
from flask_admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
# from app.models import User


from config import config
from .assets import app_css, app_js, vendor_css, vendor_js




basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

mail = Mail()
db = SQLAlchemy()
csrf = CsrfProtect()
compress = Compress()


# Set up Flask-Login
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.login_view = 'account.login'

from app.models import User


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    # not using sqlalchemy event system, hence disabling it


    with app.app_context():
        m =app.url_map

    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    # Set up extensions
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    csrf.init_app(app)
    compress.init_app(app)
    RQ(app)
    # adm = Admin(app, name='MyAPP')
    adm = Admin(endpoint='adminz', name='adz', url='/adminz')



   ......

    # Create app blueprints
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .account import account as account_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(account_blueprint, url_prefix='/account')

    from .admin import admin as admin_blueprint
    # from .admin import admin_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')

    return app
```

templates/admin/db.html:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

To the admin views (https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/blob/master/app/admin/views.py) I've added :

```
from flask_admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from app import adm as adm, db

class MyView(ModelView):
    @expose('/')
    def db(self):
        return self.render('admin/db.html')


# admin management setup
@main.route('/db')
def db():
    adm.add_view(MyView(User, db.session))
```

I'm getting the admin dashboard not the flask-admin basic view when I open:

```
 127.0.0.1:5000/db
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

following your directions I changed create_app to start with:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    # not using sqlalchemy event system, hence disabling it
    # adm = Admin(name='admin2', endpoint='/db', url='/db', template_mode='bootstrap3',base_template='admin/db.html')


    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    # Set up extensions
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    csrf.init_app(app)
    compress.init_app(app)
    RQ(app)
    adm = Admin(app, name='MyAPP')
    # adm = Admin(endpoint='adminz', name='adz', url='/adminz')
    adm.add_view(MyView(User, db.session, endpoint='db'))
```

This results in :

File "....flask\app.py", line 946, in register_blueprint
    (blueprint, self.blueprints[blueprint.name], blueprint.name)
AssertionError: A blueprint's name collision occurred between  and .  Both share the same name "admin".  Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.

EDIT2:

to the end of create_app I've added:

```
# Create app blueprints
from .main import main as main_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

from .account import account as account_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(account_blueprint, url_prefix='/account')

from .admin import admin as admin_blueprint
# from .admin import admin_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')
# app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/ab')

with app.app_context():
    m =app.url_map

return app
```

I'm not sure what you want to see but m.rules gives:

```
 <Rule '/account/manage/change-password' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.change_password>,
 <Rule '/account/manage/change-email' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.change_email_request>,
 <Rule '/account/manage/info' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.manage>,
 <Rule '/account/confirm-account' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> account.confirm_request>,
 <Rule '/account/reset-password' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.reset_password_request>,
 <Rule '/account/unconfirmed' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> account.unconfirmed>,
 <Rule '/account/register' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.register>,
 <Rule '/account/logout' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> account.logout>,
 <Rule '/account/manage' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.manage>,
 <Rule '/account/login' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.login>,
 <Rule '/admin/_update_editor_contents' (OPTIONS, POST) -> admin.update_editor_contents>,
 <Rule '/admin/invite-user' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> admin.invite_user>,
 <Rule '/admin/new-user' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> admin.new_user>,
 <Rule '/admin/users' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> admin.registered_users>,
 <Rule '/get_session_job_value' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.get_session_job_value>,
 <Rule '/cl_confirm_chrome' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> main.cl_confirm_chrome>,
 <Rule '/render_png' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.render_png>,
 <Rule '/selected' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.selected>,
 <Rule '/cl_dash' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> main.cl_dash>,
 <Rule '/about' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.about>,
 <Rule '/admin/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> admin.index>,
 <Rule '/dash' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.dash>,
 <Rule '/jobs' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.get_jobs>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.index>,
 <Rule '/account/manage/change-email/<token>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.change_email>,
 <Rule '/admin/user/<user_id>/change-account-type' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> admin.change_account_type>,
 <Rule '/admin/user/<user_id>/change-email' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> admin.change_user_email>,
 <Rule '/admin/user/<user_id>/_delete' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> admin.delete_user>,
 <Rule '/admin/user/<user_id>/delete' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> admin.delete_user_request>,
 <Rule '/admin/user/<user_id>/info' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> admin.user_info>,
 <Rule '/account/join-from-invite/<user_id>/<token>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.join_from_invite>,
 <Rule '/account/confirm-account/<token>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> account.confirm>,
 <Rule '/account/reset-password/<token>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST) -> account.reset_password>,
 <Rule '/admin/static/<filename>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> admin.static>,
 <Rule '/admin/user/<user_id>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> admin.user_info>,
 <Rule '/results/<job_key>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.get_results>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> static>
```

EDIT 3:

I have to say that is an incredible answer!  You have really taught me a lot. I have replaced the urls with the rules above following your directions. My original plan 10 days ago was just to use the basic flask-admin CRUD functionality. I'm not interested in the db.html template (its just something I tried).

anyway trying to change the name of the admin blueprint ( your number 1). I had tried this before changing app/admin/init.py to :

```
from flask import Blueprint
admin = Blueprint('admin_blueprint', __name__)
from . import views  # noqa
```

Now when I open

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/adminz/
```

I get a 404 error

FINAL EDIT:

The problem was solved by https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5819113/diego-quintana who explained that there was a conflict between flask-admin which creates a blueprint and the flask-base admin blueprint. By changing both the name of the blueprint and the static file folder of the flask-base project. Flask-admin could work without being overridden. Please see https://github.com/kc1/flask-base

Comment: Shoudn't be the `endpoint='admin/db'` ? or the page url should be `127.0.0.1:5000/admin/db` ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2018 09:30:14] "GET /admin/db HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Can u post `admin/db.html` code?

Comment: And why don't you add you views in your `create_app` factory method, by `admin.add_view(MyView(User, db.session))` instead of what you did?

Comment: You should be initializing `Admin` and registering `views` and `blueprints` _inside_ `create_app`

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be initializing `Admin` and registering `views` and `blueprints` inside `create_app`. Check if this works for you.

```
# app factory
def create_app(config_name):

    # configure current app
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    # wrap app with extensions
   ...

    # admin.init_app(app) does not work and flask-admin
    # should be instantiated inside create_app()
    # see https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/910#issuecomment-115003492
    # for details
    admin = Admin(app, name='MyAPP')

    ...

    # import models 
    from .models.user import User
    # more imports happening here

    # import flask-admin views to be used in the admin panel
    from .admin.views import MyView


    # register admin view forms
    admin.add_view(MyView(name='MyCustomView', endpoint='db'))

    # register blueprints
    # ...

    # implementation of the app factory pattern
    return app
```

EDIT:

What I believe is happening is that

- The app in the repo has already a blueprint named `admin` living in /admin
- You want to implement `flask-admin` in the app, but it clashes with the existing blueprint

You can achieve this doing two things:

1. Change the current `blueprint` name in the repo to something different from `admin`, since `flask-admin` clashes with it. (Reading from your github issue it seems the are a lot of hardcoded internals for `admin.static`, which makes changing the current `admin` blueprint *easier*.

the anatomy of a Blueprint is kinda like this

```
# app/myblueprint/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint

# a random blueprint
myblueprint = Blueprint(name='mycustomblueprint', 
                         import_name=__name__, # name of the file
                         static_folder='static', # a folder inside app/myblueprint/static
                         template_folder='templates', # a folder inside app/myblueprint/templates
                         static_url_path='/static', # this is what mycustomblueprint.static will point to, and if the name is admin it will be admin.static, thus colliding with flask-admin
                         url_prefix='/myblueprintprefix', # this will be appended to each view inside your blueprint, i.e. a view '/foo' will get converted into '/myblueprintprefix/foo' in your url mappings
                         subdomain=None,
                         url_defaults=None,
                         root_path=None)

from . import views # import the views inside app/myblueprint/views.py
```

then, you import it inside `create_app` as

```
from .myblueprint import myblueprint as my_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint) # notice I've defined url_prefix in the Blueprint definition. You can do it at registration time, it's up to you
```

tl;dr: change the `admin` blueprint since it's clashing with `flask-admin`

2. `flask-admin` works based in views, and the pattern to generate admin views is by *importing* them and passing an `url` parameter that gets appended to the `/admin` endpoint (where `flask-admin` lives). 
   In this case, you can think of two flavours (more but for the sake of the example it's okay)

   - `ModelView`, which you use to create custom CRUD views and takes both a `model` and a `db.session` object.
   - `BaseView` which you use to extend a generic view inside the `admin` blueprint used by `flask-admin`.

This means, if you want to render your own `db.html` file inside the `flask-admin` views, you have to do:

```
# app/modelviews/mycustomviews.py
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose

class DBView(BaseView): # notice I'm using BaseView and not ModelView
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('modelviews/db.html') # this file should live in app/templates/modelviews/db.html
```

and inside `create_app`

```
# register admin view forms
from .modelviews import DBView
admin.add_view(DBView(name='MyCustomView', endpoint='db')) # this will show up in your `flask-admin` main view as MyCustomView, and it will live in {host}/admin/db
```

You can also check in your `url_map` parameter of the flask app in context that you have. You don't need this bit in your `create_app`

```
with app.app_context():
m =app.url_map
```

I mentioned it because it could help you debug your views inside the python `repl`. Import your app, and follow the gist I've provided. The `url_map` should return something like a list of `<Rules>`

```
 [<Rule '/admin/' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> admin.index>,
 <Rule '/admin/db' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> dbview.index>]
```

This way you can confirm that your view lives where it should. Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help. It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Hi Diego, You can see the entire issue at https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/issues/168 - I still don't have an answer

Comment: A few things after looking at your latest code:

1. `endpoint` should *not* have backslashes. You can confirm the endpoint mappings for your app by pushing a context [1] and checking `app.url_map`.

2.  You should not be doing admin.init_app(app), check the github issue I've mentioned in my example.

[1] https://gist.github.com/diegoquintanav/45cef416ce5e8cc819afd12b91eac2e5

Comment: 3. Don't use the 'admin' name as a blueprint name or endpoint name since it is used by `flask-admin`. In this case you could register a complete View by doing `admin.add_view(MyView(MyModel, db.session, name='SomeViewName', endpoint='db'))`

Comment: @user61629 a flask application lives inside a context, which handles its lifecycle as its configuration parameters. Check http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/

Comment: Thank you, I also took a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036520/what-is-the-purpose-of-flasks-context-stacks. So if I understand correctly a context refers to the local variables of a thread or greenlet.

Comment: I have to say that is an incredible answer!  You have really taught me a lot. I have replaced the urls with the rules above following your directions. My original plan 10 days ago was just to use the basic flask-admin CRUD functionality. I'm not interested in the db.html template (its just something I tried).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170644/discussion-between-diego-quintana-and-user61629).

Answer (score 2):

Use `url` instead of `endpoint`

```
adm = Admin(name='test',url='/db')
```

Comment: when I do that I get AssertionError: A blueprint's name collision occurred between <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x000001EB35D2D240> and <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x000001EB35A59198>.  Both share the same name "admin".  Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.

Comment: Havi you tried giving it another name? `adm = Admin(name='admin2', url='/db')`

Comment: I tried that but that gives the same error. There is a pre-existing blueprint called admin in the project (see https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/blob/master/app/__init__.py)

Comment: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/#flask.ext.admin.base.Admin

Comment: I have a follow up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308051/importerror-cannot-import-name-db, if you are interested.