# ImportError: cannot import name 'db'

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

[image]

I am working on adding flask admin to a preexisting flask boiler plate project. I've been able to get the basic project working at https://github.com/kc1/flask-base (SCREENSHOT). I now need to add modelviews to add basic CRUD functionality. To do this I changed the code to :

```
adm = Admin(app,name='flaskadmin')
from app.models import User
adm.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
```

[image]

You can see that it works. But if I import the User model with the rest of the imports at the top of app/init I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...flask-base/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    from app import create_app, db
  File "E:\ENVS\r3\flask-base\app\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from app.models import User
  File "E:\ENVS\r3\flask-base\app\models\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .user import *  # noqa
  File "E:\ENVS\r3\flask-base\app\models\user.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .. import db, login_manager
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'
```

Why?

Comment: what is the module `db`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flask - blueprint - sqlalchemy - cannot import name 'db' into moles file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828711/flask-blueprint-sqlalchemy-cannot-import-name-db-into-moles-file)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`User` is a `Flask-SQLAlchemy` model that wraps models using SQLalchemy's API. It inherits all of its models from a `db` object, which I assume you are instantiating or registering inside a `create_app` method.

So, you should have something like this

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)

    adm = Admin(app,name='flaskadmin')
    from app.models import User
    adm.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
    return app
```

Whenever you import `User` from `user.py` you are basically importing `db.Model`, which requires for `db` to exists and actually contain data. Be wary of [circular imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909816/can-i-avoid-circular-imports-in-flask-and-sqlalchemy) in Flask and in Python in general.

The error you are receiving is clearly stated in the error traceback

```
  File "E:\ENVS\r3\flask-base\app\models\user.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .. import db, login_manager
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'
```

This is, in `user.py` there is an import of `db` from `../__init__.py` but in that file there is an import of `User` happening before the definition of `db`.

A `db` object emulates the [`declarative` approach from SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/), where the object holds data about every other Class that inherited from it.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer! I think one problem I have is understanding the order that flask files are executed when you run them, in a more complex flask project like this. I'll ask a follow up question on this later.